# How to get the json data in a var script from a website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the JSON data that I see when inspecting the page source for a particular URL. This is the url: https://www.uniqlo.com/de/de/product/ut-bedrucktes-t-shirt-kaws-summer-421771.html

My goal is to get the "pricing" and the "availability" for "ats":"xxx"

Here is a part of the sourcecode:

```html
</div>
<div class="product-detail">

<script>
var pdpVariationsJSON = 

{"color-COL08|size-SMA002":{"id":"421771COL08SMA002000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XS"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"203","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA003":{"id":"421771COL08SMA003000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"S"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"106","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA004":{"id":"421771COL08SMA004000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"M"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"218","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA005":{"id":"421771COL08SMA005000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"L"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"7","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA006":{"id":"421771COL08SMA006000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XL"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"83","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA007":{"id":"421771COL08SMA007000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XXL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA008":{"id":"421771COL08SMA008000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"3XL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA002":{"id":"421771COL68SMA002000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XS"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"159","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA003":{"id":"421771COL68SMA003000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"S"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA004":{"id":"421771COL68SMA004000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"M"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"63","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA005":{"id":"421771COL68SMA005000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"L"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"9","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA006":{"id":"421771COL68SMA006000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XL"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"136","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA007":{"id":"421771COL68SMA007000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XXL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA008":{"id":"421771COL68SMA008000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"3XL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}}}
;
</script>

<div id="product-content">
```

I've tryed it with json.loads() but this gets me this error:

"raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

This is what my code snipet looks like till now:

```py
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import json

url = "https://www.uniqlo.com/de/de/product/ut-bedrucktes-t-shirt-kaws-summer-421771.html"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")



div = soup.find("div", class_="product-detail")

scr = str(div.find("script"))

print(scr)
```

This is what i got now as result when printing:

```py
<script>
var pdpVariationsJSON = 

{"color-COL08|size-SMA002":{"id":"421771COL08SMA002000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XS"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"203","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA003":{"id":"421771COL08SMA003000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"S"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"106","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA004":{"id":"421771COL08SMA004000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"M"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"218","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA005":{"id":"421771COL08SMA005000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"L"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"7","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA006":{"id":"421771COL08SMA006000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XL"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"83","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA007":{"id":"421771COL08SMA007000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"XXL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL08|size-SMA008":{"id":"421771COL08SMA008000","attributes":{"color":"Dunkelgrau","size":"3XL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA002":{"id":"421771COL68SMA002000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XS"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"159","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA003":{"id":"421771COL68SMA003000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"S"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA004":{"id":"421771COL68SMA004000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"M"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"63","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA005":{"id":"421771COL68SMA005000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"L"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"9","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA006":{"id":"421771COL68SMA006000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XL"},"availability":{"status":"IN_STOCK","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":true,"ats":"136","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":true,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":1,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":0},"isAvailable":true,"inStockMsg":"1 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA007":{"id":"421771COL68SMA007000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"XXL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}},"color-COL68|size-SMA008":{"id":"421771COL68SMA008000","attributes":{"color":"Blau","size":"3XL"},"availability":{"status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","statusQuantity":"0","inStock":false,"ats":"0","inStockDate":"","availableForSale":false,"purchaseLevel":"","levels":{"IN_STOCK":0,"PREORDER":0,"BACKORDER":0,"NOT_AVAILABLE":1},"isAvailable":false,"inStockMsg":"0 Produkt(e) verfügbar","preOrderMsg":"0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verfügbar.","backOrderMsg":"Back Order 0 item(s)"},"pricing":{"showStandardPrice":false,"isPromoPrice":false,"standard":14.9,"formattedStandard":"14,90 €","sale":14.9,"formattedSale":"14,90 €","salePriceMoney":{},"standardPriceMoney":{},"quantities":[{"unit":"","value":0}]}}}
;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re` to extract the important part from the `<script>` tag and use `json.loads` to parse it:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.uniqlo.com/de/de/product/ut-bedrucktes-t-shirt-kaws-summer-421771.html"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

div = soup.find("div", class_="product-detail")
scr = str(div.find("script"))

data = json.loads(re.findall(r'pdpVariationsJSON[^{]+(.*);', str(scr), flags=re.DOTALL)[0])

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "color-COL08|size-SMA002": {
        "id": "421771COL08SMA002000",
        "attributes": {
            "color": "Dunkelgrau",
            "size": "XS"
        },
        "availability": {
            "status": "IN_STOCK",
            "statusQuantity": "0",
            "inStock": true,
            "ats": "203",
            "inStockDate": "",
            "availableForSale": true,
            "purchaseLevel": "",
            "levels": {
                "IN_STOCK": 1,
                "PREORDER": 0,
                "BACKORDER": 0,
                "NOT_AVAILABLE": 0
            },
            "isAvailable": true,
            "inStockMsg": "1 Produkt(e) verf\u00fcgbar",
            "preOrderMsg": "0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verf\u00fcgbar.",
            "backOrderMsg": "Back Order 0 item(s)"
        },
        "pricing": {
            "showStandardPrice": false,
            "isPromoPrice": false,
            "standard": 14.9,
            "formattedStandard": "14,90 \u20ac",
            "sale": 14.9,
            "formattedSale": "14,90 \u20ac",
            "salePriceMoney": {},
            "standardPriceMoney": {},
            "quantities": [
                {
                    "unit": "",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "color-COL08|size-SMA003": {
        "id": "421771COL08SMA003000",
        "attributes": {
            "color": "Dunkelgrau",
            "size": "S"
        },
        "availability": {
            "status": "IN_STOCK",
            "statusQuantity": "0",
            "inStock": true,
            "ats": "106",
            "inStockDate": "",
            "availableForSale": true,
            "purchaseLevel": "",
            "levels": {
                "IN_STOCK": 1,
                "PREORDER": 0,
                "BACKORDER": 0,
                "NOT_AVAILABLE": 0
            },
            "isAvailable": true,
            "inStockMsg": "1 Produkt(e) verf\u00fcgbar",
            "preOrderMsg": "0 Produkt(e) sind zur Vorbestellung verf\u00fcgbar.",
            "backOrderMsg": "Back Order 0 item(s)"
        },
        "pricing": {
            "showStandardPrice": false,
            "isPromoPrice": false,
            "standard": 14.9,
            "formattedStandard": "14,90 \u20ac",
            "sale": 14.9,
            "formattedSale": "14,90 \u20ac",
            "salePriceMoney": {},
            "standardPriceMoney": {},
            "quantities": [
                {
                    "unit": "",
                    "value": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    },

... and so on.
```